# hide and show by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code by html

```
<div id="a1"><input type="text" id="ac1" /></div>
<div id="a2" style="display:none"><input type="text" id="ac2" /></div>
<div id="a3" style="display:none"><input type="text" id="ac3" /></div>
<div id="a4" style="display:none"><input type="text" id="ac4" /></div>
<div id="a5" style="display:none"><input type="text" id="ac5" /></div>
<div id="a6" style="display:none"><input type="text" id="ac6" /></div><span id="close" style="display:none">X</span>
<div><input type="button" id="add" value="add" /></div>
```

and this code by javascript

```
var i = 2;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){
    if(i <= 6){
        $("#a"+i).show(500);
        ++i;
        if (i == 7){ $(this).hide(500); }
        if (i >= 2){ $("#close").show(500); }
    }
    });

    $("#close").click(function(){
        --i;
        $("#a"+i).hide(500);
        $("#ac"+i).val("");
        if (i == 2){ $(this).hide(500); }
        if (i == 6){ $("#add").show(500); }
    });
});
```

i need when click add button i need hide the last one and put new above it

Comment: add what? Where? be more specific, pls

Comment: I think you mean jQuery not ajax

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply reverse the order of your html inputs

```
<div id="a6" style="display:none"><input type="text" id="ac6" />
<div id="a5" style="display:none"><input type="text" id="ac5" /></div>

a4
a3
a2
a1
```

Comment: When you add a new form, the old disappears and shows the new